# Why is my function not running in the zone?

Tags: angular

## The Problem

I've been staring at this for a couple of hours now, I don't understand why my final function is not being run in the zone.

My function order is as follows:

```
onFormSubmit() > getPhoneData() > getEligibility()
```

`onFormSubmit()` is run in the zone, but by the time we get past the `getPhoneData()` function, we are no longer running in the zone. So when I update the error flag `this.errored` from false to true, it gets updated, and can be logged as being set correctly, however this update is not reflected in the zone. **This only happens when the `getPhoneDataFunction` is forced to make an HTTP request for data.**  You will notice that in this function I have forced it to run in the zone by using NgZone, but ideally I'd like to not have to do this as I feel like it's a hack.

#### onFormSubmit()

This function is the root function.  It calls `getPhoneData()` first, which returns a promise.  It then calls `getElligibility()` inside the `.then()` callback.

```
onFormSubmit( event ): void {

  // Stop it, browser!
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();

  // Ok let's get the phone data
  this.getPhoneData().then( phoneData => {

    // Check the users elligibility
    this.getEligibility(phoneData);
  })
}
```

#### getPhoneData()

This function returns a promise and returns either the existing data that has already been retrieved, or makes an HTTP call to get the data.

```
// Gets phone data and returns it
getPhoneData(): any {
  return Promise( (resolve, reject) => {

    // If we already have phone data
    if ( this.phoneData){

      // Resolve with the existing data
      resolve(this.phoneData);

    // Otherwise attempt to get the phone data
    } else {

      // We are now loading
      this.loading = true;

      // Create headers
      const headers = new Headers();

      // Create the authentication header
      headers.append(CENSORED);

      // Create the request options object
      const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

      // Get the phone number information
      this.httpService.get(this.phoneDataUrl, options).subscribe( results => {

        // Get the phone number data from the results object, split on line returns and remove any empty strings
        this.phoneData = results.text().split(/\r?\n/g).filter( string => string.length );

        // We are no longer loading
        this.loading = false;

        // Resolve the promise
        resolve(this.phoneData);
      })
    }
  })
}
```

#### getEligibility()

This function simply checks the users input number against a white-list of numbers and either sets the error flag `this.errored` to true or does other tasks if the number was eligible.  **This is where the problem is, when I set the flag at this point, it updates the property, however that update is not reflected in the DOM.**

```
// Checks elligibility
getEligibility( phoneData: string[] ): void {

  // Get just the numbers from whatever the user input
  const cleanNumber = this.userPhoneNumber.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");

  // Get whether the user is eligible or not
  const isEligible = phoneData.map( number => number === cleanNumber ).includes(true);

  // If the user is not eligible
  if ( !isEligible ){

    // Make sure this runs in the zone
    this.zone.run( () => {

      // Show the error state
      this.errored = true;
    });

  } else {

    // Do other stuff
  }
}
```

## The Solution

Is there a way to accomplish having this function run in the zone so the DOM updates, or is this "hack" the only way to get the job done?  Can someone please point me in the direction of what I am missing?

Comment: Does it work if you don't use a Promise?

Comment: Are you using OnPush CD?

Comment: It does work if I eliminate the promise and put the callbacks into the HTTP request itself, but this is definitely not what I am after.

Comment: @funkizer Nope.

Comment: Try swapping the boolean errored with BehaviorSubject<boolean> and instead of setting it call errored.next(true), in template: errored|async

Comment: @StephenRios - By "the callbacks", you mean `getEligibility`?

Comment: @ConnorsFan yep

Comment: I assume httpService uses angular HttpClient? if not, that's the prob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the code so that `getPhoneData` returns an Observable instead of a Promise. You would subscribe to it in `onFormSubmit`.

```
onFormSubmit( event ): void {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  this.getPhoneData().subscribe(phoneData => {
    this.getEligibility(phoneData);
  });
}
```

```
getPhoneData(): Observable<any> {
  if (this.phoneData){
    return Observable.of(this.phoneData);
  } else {
    this.loading = true;
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append(CENSORED);
    const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    return this.httpService.get(this.phoneDataUrl, options)
      .do(results => {
        this.phoneData = results.text().split(/\r?\n/g).filter(string => string.length);
        this.loading = false;
      }
      .map(results => this.phoneData);
  }
}
```